# How can I mod Minecraft 1.7.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've looked up a lot of tutorials on YouTube and all of them only work for versions of Minecraft prior to 1.7.9.

I first got a Minecraft Coder Pack (MCP) off of [this website](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/download.php?list.2), but then realized that only decompiles Minecraft 1.6.4. Then I found a more recent MCP (that's not on the website for some reason) and it is version 9.03, downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/q97ptg3ng85tpra/mcp903.zip). This decompiles Minecraft version 1.7.2 (when I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lsv-S9--Z8)'s instructions, I run the decompile.bat file and it says `Json file not found in C:\Users\mike\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2.json`).

Basically I can't decompile Minecraft 1.7.9, but I can decompile older versions. However, I don't have any older versions downloaded onto my computer. I have only 1.7.9.

Then I tried using Forge, but realized that most videos were using versions of Minecraft prior to 1.6.4, meaning they use the bin folder that does not exist anymore. Even after trying to figure that out as well, the decompiling would never work. I tried to do what [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klYTEMiATZw) did, but couldn't replicate it. Then I finally looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkRAW7gTnWw) about using Forge and I could replicate it, but this didn't decompile Minecraft. It just set up a workspace in Eclipse that I'm not sure how to use.

**TL;DR**

**I can decompile Minecraft 1.6.4 and 1.7.2 but I can't decompile version 1.7.9. Should I download an older version of Minecraft, wait for an MCP for 1.7.9, or something else? Is there something I'm missing, where I actually can decompile and mod Minecraft 1.7.9?**

Comment: @Frank mod development, not installation

Comment: @Frank How is this a duplicate of that? First of all, it's not the same question. And secondly, the solution to that problem does not work for me. What's your reasoning?

Comment: Reading your question, I came to the impression that you're attempting to get mods working on a specific version of Minecraft.  Just because the solutions don't work doesn't mean we allow questions asking the same thing.  By @3ventic's interpretation, though, you're asking specifically how to go about developing mods for Minecraft.  In which case, it's not a duplicate, but totally off-topic, as development questions don't belong here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Frank Wouldn't both be considered off-topic anyways? But yes, I see now that this is off-topic. This should be migrated over to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nice. Apparently this is a duplicate and there's no answer out there and no similar question. Perfect.